# File not ready for write after open?

Tags: python, linux, gpio, file-access

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

export = open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w')
export.write('44\n')
```

And this code produces the following output:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

If I change the code by adding a export.close() to the end, I get this as output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    export.close()
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

However, if I change the code again as such, it works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep

export = open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w')
sleep(1)
export.write('44\n')
```

Note that .close ALWAYS fails, even if I put a long sleep after the write.

Edit:

Changed my code to be the following:

```
with open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w') as export:
    sleep(1)
    export.write('44\n')
    export.flush()
    export.close()
```

Still gives errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
    export.flush()
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

Edit 2:

My main issue turned out to be that you can't export a GPIO that has already been exported.  I've updated my code to look like this and it seems to be working:

```
from os import path

if not path.isdir('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w') as export:
        export.write('44\n')

if path.exists('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/direction'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/direction', 'w') as gpio44_dir:
        gpio44_dir.write('out\n')

if path.exists('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value', 'w') as gpio44_val:
        gpio44_val.write('1\n')
```

This code successfully exports a GPIO, sets its direction to "out", and actives it (value to 1).

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but what if you do `export.flush()` before closing?

Comment: Is `/sys/class/gpio/export` a normal file?

Comment: Could you try using python context manager? like that:
with open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w') as export:
    export.write(...)

Comment: I'll try those suggestions.No, I don't think it's a normal file.  It's an interface to the kernel for exporting GPIOs (this is on an embedded device, a beaglebone black)

Comment: "flush" and "with" did not seem to help (see post)

Comment: how about changing 'w' mode to 'a' (append) ?

Comment: On my system, this file appears to be part of a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-mounted virtual filesystem, which have special access rights restrictions (see, e.g., [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23074/what-means-this-error-message-lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfs-fuse-daemon/23199#23199)). Can you `lsof` or `stat` this file normally? Presumably not. Are you running this program as the user who mounted that filesystem (I'm assuming root)? Presumably not.

Comment: Does anything [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118716/62699) help you?

Comment: Yes, I can lsof and stat.  lsof returns nothing.  stat describes it as a "regular file"

Comment: Yes I am running as root.  And no, the link doesn't help.  They are using echo and file direction which works fine.  Meaning, if I do: echo 44 > /sys/class/gpio/export, it works without error.  So what is the redirect doing behind the scenes that my python code isn't?

Comment: One more clarification: you are running `echo 44 > /sys/class/gpio/export` on a root shell and it works? As well as `lsof` and `stat`? If so, then my best advice is to tag the particular version of Linux you've installed on this device to hopefully get some experts using systems that are configured more closely to yours. If not, however, I think you need to run your Python script as whatever user you are running the successful normal commands with, even if that is your regular user.

Comment: I'm also reaching, but two things come to mind: are you sure you need to include the newline `\n` character, because that does not seem typical / is nothing else using or blocking the port and have you tried other ports?

Comment: So, first to answer some of your questions.  Yes, everything is owned and run by root.  Yes, the newline is required (note that the echo command is also adding a newline).  I tried switching to append and it actually worked.  I thought because of append, but actually because I had rebooted my development board.

Comment: Why did that fix it?  Because apparently you can only do this operation once.  If you try and export a GPIO while it's already been exported, that's when you get all these weird errors.  So I've updated my code to check if the export is even needed first, and I think I'm either working now, or have at least made great progress.  Thanks guys so much for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main issue turned out to be that you can't export a GPIO that has already been exported. I've updated my code to look like this and it seems to be working:

```
from os import path

if not path.isdir('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/export', 'w') as export:
        export.write('44\n')

if path.exists('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/direction'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/direction', 'w') as gpio44_dir:
        gpio44_dir.write('out\n')

if path.exists('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value'):
    with open('/sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value', 'w') as gpio44_val:
        gpio44_val.write('1\n')
```

This code successfully exports a GPIO, sets its direction to "out", and actives it (value to 1).

Comment: Well if nothing else you get the troubleshooting merit badge.